# Finding the lowest value y can have in $y = \frac{1}{2}(e^x - e^{-x}) + \frac{n}{2}(e^x + e^{-x }) $

Tags: functions

How can I find the lowest value $y$ can have when $n$ is greater than or equal to $2$ using only algebra?

$$y = \frac{1}{2}(e^x - e^{-x}) + \frac{n}{2}(e^x + e^{-x })$$

Comment: Can you re-edit your post to make it more readable pls? Do you mean $\frac{1}{2(e^x - e^{-x})} + \frac{n}{2}(e^x + e^{-x }) $

Comment: if $n\leq 0$ the function is unbounded from below.

Comment: I do not have the time at the moment to post a full solution, but one could do this by re expressing the given equation as a quadratic in terms of the exponential function, and then using the discriminant. If somebody could turn this idea into an answer, I would really appreciate it as I think it would work nicely with what OP wants (no calculus, I presume)

Comment: @Trogdor can you post it?

Answer (score 3):

Using [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)
$$
y=\frac{(n+1)e^x+(n-1)e^{-x}}{2}\ge\sqrt{(n+1)(n-1)}=\sqrt{n^2-1}.
$$
Equality when $(n+1)e^x=(n-1)e^{-x}$ $\Rightarrow$ $x=\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{n-1}{n+1}$.

Comment: Nice and very short...

Comment: @johannesvalks Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

The minimum or maximum would be reached when $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$.

So, consider $$y =  \frac{1}{2}(e^x - e^{-x})  + \frac{n}{2}(e^x + e^{-x
})$$ Compute $\frac{dy}{dx}$, set it equal to $0$, solve for $x$ (which will be a function of $n$) and plug the value back in $y$.

Do not forget to use the second derivative test to verify that $y$ is at a minimum.

Comment: Is there any other way except using differentiation

Comment: @jessij. I do not think. What is your difficulty with that ? Please, explain.

Comment: Yes, a smart way will be to substitute some values of $n$ and $x$ in the equation, and see where the maximal/minimum is likely to be...but this is not something suitable for a Maths student as everyone can do it.

Comment: @Chuks. I agree with you. Moreover, the problem and solution are really nice ! Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Actually, you can find the solution without differentiation...

Answer (score 0):

## Solution without differentiation.

Given is
$$
y = \frac{1}{2} \Big( \exp(x) - \exp(-x) \Big)
+ \frac{n}{2} \Big( \exp(x) + \exp(-x) \Big).
$$

---

*Step 1:*
$$
y = \frac{n+1}{2} \exp(x) + \frac{n-1}{2} \exp(-x).
$$

---

*Step 2:*
$$
y = \frac{n+1}{2} \exp(-a) \exp(x+a) + \frac{n-1}{2} \exp(a) \exp(-[x+a]).
$$

---

*Step 3:*
Find $a$ such that
$$
\frac{n+1}{2} \exp(-a) : \frac{n-1}{2} \exp(a) = 1,
$$

so solve

$$
\frac{n+1}{n-1} \exp(-2a) = 1 \Rightarrow a = \log \sqrt{ \frac{n+1}{n-1} }.
$$

---

*Step 4:*
$$
y = \frac{\sqrt{n^2-1}}{2}
\Big[ \exp(x+a) + \exp(-[x+a]) \Big]
$$

---

*Step 5:*
$$
y = \sqrt{n^2-1}
\Bigg[ 1 + \Big[ \tfrac{1}{2} \exp(\tfrac{1}{2}[x+a])
- \tfrac{1}{2}\exp(-\tfrac{1}{2} [x+a]) \Big]^2  \Bigg]
$$

You can read out the minimum, as $y$ has the form $y = a ( 1 + \xi^2)$.
The minimum is $a$ for $\xi=0$.

The minimum is given by
$$
\sqrt{n^2-1}
$$

for
$$
x = \frac{1}{2} \log \frac{n-1}{n+1}.
$$

Comment: @ Johannesvalks, because you want to add your answer, you start marking everyone's answer down....that's very bad of you!!! The original post didn't say without differentiation...go and check!

Comment: @Chuks, precisely, its just ridiculous!

Comment: @ John, if not that we are learned individuals here, we would have given him -30 downvotes on this answer...so he will know that people have to spend some energy and time to type some reasonable things.

Comment: @Chuks, the OP askes to use algebra only. Voting is based on answers based on the OP. It happens to me too, when I reply that is not what is asked in the OP. That is the way how it goes.